# How to disable chunking in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip

When using mod_deflate in Apache2, Apache will chunk gzipped content, setting the Transfer-encoding: chunked header.

Is there any setting that would change Apache's default behavior, and have Apache set a Content-length header instead of chunking the response?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to disable Chunked encoding? IIRC it's a *requirement* in HTTP/1.1 whenever any other encoding type is set & HTTP keepalive is in use.

Answer (score 1):

That would mean Apache would have to buffer the compressed output just to calculate the content-length before sending any of the response. I don't know of such a setting, and I'd be surprised if it was supported.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SetEnv force-response-1.0 1 ?